# How do I create a horizontal line of divs, some of which flow to the right? All divs should be vertically aligned

Tags: css, position

Perhaps it will be easiest to show what I'd like to achieve on an example:

```css
header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}

header > div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div><h1>Title</h1></div>
    <div>Blah1</div>
    <div>Blah2</div>
    <div style="float: right;">Blah4</div>
    <div style="float: right;">Blah3</div>
</header>
```

I hope the problem is clear... I want my `div`s to line up horizontally in the `header`. To achieve this, I reason, I should make these `div`s `inline-block`. And this works.

Except one thing... I want some of these `div`s to float to the right of the page, rather than to the left. But then, no matter what I do, these `div`s refuse to vertically align themsleves to the middle of the enclosing container. As you can see, Blah3 and Blah4 are far too much to the top, which looks ugly.

I was reasoning that if I use `height: 100%` I'll force the rightmost `div`s to be as tall as the encloding `header`, and then, if I use `vertical-align: middle` I'll vertically position the text in the, well, middle; but as you can see this is not the case.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather suggest you the ***Flexbox*** solution:

```css
header {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  align-items: center; /* centers them vertically */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}

header > div {padding: 10px}

header > div:nth-child(3) {margin-right: auto} /* pushes the other two siblings far right to the end of the row */
```

```html
<header>
  <div><h1>Title</h1></div>
  <div>Blah1</div>
  <div>Blah2</div>
  <div>Blah4</div>
  <div>Blah3</div>
</header>
```